# Given a list of objects want that object to return the list-object it is stored into

Tags: python, class, oop

So I am creating some sort of structure where one object with higher hierarchy has some attributes and a list of other objects with lower hierarchy. Is it possible to build a method for the object of lower hierarchy to return the object in which list it is stored to? I am not talking about class inheritance since the two classes are completely different. The code is something like that:

```
class List_object:
    def __init__(self,*elements):
        self.list = []
        for e in elements:
            self.list.append(e)

class Element:
    def __init__(self,name)
        self.name = name

    def get_parent_list():
        # do some magic to return the object made in List_object
    
    el = Element("Alpha")
    L = List_object(el)
```

now calling el.get_parent_list() i would like to have it return the object L. Is that even possible? How should the get_parent_list function be defined?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide required output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class List_object:
    def __init__(self,*elements):
        self.list = []
        for e in elements:
            self.list.append(e)
            e.parent.append(self)
class Element:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.parent= []
    def get_parent_list(self):
        return self.parent
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work!!! One more noob thing the object returned by `return self.parent`  is a reference right? I mean:`el = Element("Alpha")
    L = List_object(el)    q = el.get_parent_list` can I call methods of the List_object by calling q[0].method ??

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [@hr.mousavi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11088493/hr-mousavi) answer, he was faster than me, you could do it as follow.

**Note**: I don't think this way of doing things is very clean.

```py
class List_object:
    def __init__(self,*elements):
        self.list = []
        for e in elements:
            e.parent = self
            e.parent.append(self)

class Element:
    def __init__(self,name, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
    def get_parent_list(self):
        return self.parent
```

**Example:**

```py
el = Element("Alopha")
L = List_object(el)
el.get_parent_list()
```

**Output:**

```py
<__main__.List_object at 0x7f88371d5210>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did some testing and all looks fine. I know it is not the cleanest thing...but imagine for example that the list object is a team and the element is a player. When you operate with the player object (and not necessarily know his team) some actions (methods) have an effect on the team he is playing for.

Comment: [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14644960/peter) you should mark one of the two answer as correct. In case they solve your problem.